# Fitting an ellipse to a set of 2-D points

Tags: python-3.x, ellipse, data-fitting

I'm trying to fit an ellipse to a set of points described by x and y coordinates.

I found a detailed explanation of how to do it here http://nicky.vanforeest.com/misc/fitEllipse/fitEllipse.html
and tried out the code, but it doesn't seem to work.

It finds the center correctly, but the angle and axes are completely wrong, as you can see in this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/25l7Y.png

The red points are my data points and the blue aptch is an ellipse drawn from the obtained parameters. Now, the data isn't a perfect ellipse, but the fit is nowhere near it. I'd like to get the fit closer to the actual data.

Here's the code in question.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig, inv

def fitEllipse(x,y):
    x = x[:,np.newaxis]
    y = y[:,np.newaxis]
    D =  np.hstack((x*x, x*y, y*y, x, y, np.ones_like(x)))
    S = np.dot(D.T,D)
    C = np.zeros([6,6])
    C[0,2] = C[2,0] = 2; C[1,1] = -1
    E, V =  eig(np.dot(inv(S), C))
    n = np.argmax(np.abs(E))
    a = V[:,n]
    return a

def ellipse_center(a):
    b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
    num = b*b-a*c
    x0=(c*d-b*f)/num
    y0=(a*f-b*d)/num
    return np.array([x0,y0])


def ellipse_angle_of_rotation( a ):
    b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
    return 0.5*np.arctan(2*b/(a-c))


def ellipse_axis_length( a ):
    b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
    up = 2*(a*f*f+c*d*d+g*b*b-2*b*d*f-a*c*g)
    down1=(b*b-a*c)*( (c-a)*np.sqrt(1+4*b*b/((a-c)*(a-c)))-(c+a))
    down2=(b*b-a*c)*( (a-c)*np.sqrt(1+4*b*b/((a-c)*(a-c)))-(c+a))
    res1=np.sqrt(up/down1)
    res2=np.sqrt(up/down2)
    return np.array([res1, res2])

def ellipse_angle_of_rotation2( a ):
    b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
    if b == 0:
        if a > c:
            return 0
        else:
            return np.pi/2
    else: 
        if a > c:
            return np.arctan(2*b/(a-c))/2
        else:
            return np.pi/2 + np.arctan(2*b/(a-c))/2
```

And here's my full dataset. Does anyone have any idea why it's not being fitted correctly?

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
x = np.array([ 5727.53135,  7147.62235, 10330.93573,  8711.17228, 7630.40262,
        4777.24983,  4828.27655,  9449.94416,  5203.81323,  6299.44811,
        6494.21906])

y = np.array([67157.77567 , 66568.50068 , 55922.56257 , 54887.47348 ,
       65150.14064 , 66529.91705 , 65934.25548 , 55351.57612 ,
       63123.5103  , 67181.141725, 56321.36025 ])
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


a = fitEllipse(x,y)
center = ellipse_center(a)
#phi = ellipse_angle_of_rotation(a)
phi = ellipse_angle_of_rotation2(a)
axes = ellipse_axis_length(a)

# get the individual axes
a, b = axes

from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ell = Ellipse(center, a, b, phi)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})
ax.add_artist(ell)
ell.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
ax.set_xlim(0, 100000)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100000)
plt.show()
scat = plt.scatter(x, y, c = "r")
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is absolutely fine, it is the `patch` definition that makes the trouble here.
`a` and `b` of `Ellipse` are the full width. So you have to multiply the result of your fit by `2`. Moreover the angle is in degree so you have to multiply by `180/np.pi`. Finally, the zero is not at the same position, so you have to add `90`.

Long story short change

```
Ellipse(center, a, b, phi)
```

to

```
ell = Ellipse(center, 2 * a, 2 * b,  phi * 180 / np.pi + 90 )
```

and you are good.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought of that, but glad you pointed it out!

Comment: Can you explain a little more why you recommend adding 90 to the angle here? For some of my ellipses, they only fit when I add 90, but others only fit when I don't add 90.

Comment: @iamfrank Hi, the 90 degree is an offset coming in, only due to the definition of the plotting routine in use. It is fixed and there is no "only if". If you need to add 90 degree only in some cases of your fitted data, I assume you have a different problem. Maybe you can post it with some (generic) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @mikuszefski Thanks for the insight. Got it fixed!