# Fitting an ellipse to points: why an ellipse fits for some datasets while for others there is an offset of 90 deg?

Tags: python-3.x, ellipse, data-fitting

I have trouble fitting an ellipse to a set of 2D data points. The code seems to work for some datasets, while for others the ellipse is rotated 90 degrees but always has the right shape and center. I am trying to make the SAME code work for all the datasets. Here is the code (from  https://github.com/ndvanforeest/fit_ellipse):

I have already looked at [Fitting an ellipse to a set of 2-D points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52818206/fitting-an-ellipse-to-a-set-of-2-d-points/52877062#52877062) but I still have the problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from numpy.linalg import eig, inv
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

def fitEllipse(x,y):
        x = x[:,np.newaxis]
        y = y[:,np.newaxis]
        D =  np.hstack((x*x, x*y, y*y, x, y, np.ones_like(x)))
        S = np.dot(D.T,D)
        C = np.zeros([6,6])
        C[0,2] = C[2,0] = 2; C[1,1] = -1
        E, V =  eig(np.dot(inv(S), C))
        n = np.argmax(np.abs(E))
        a = V[:,n]
        return a

def ellipse_center(a):
        b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
        num = b*b-a*c
        x0=(c*d-b*f)/num
        y0=(a*f-b*d)/num
        return np.array([x0,y0])

def ellipse_angle_of_rotation( a ):
        b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
        return 0.5*np.arctan(2*b/(a-c))

def ellipse_axis_length( a ):
        b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
        up = 2*(a*f*f+c*d*d+g*b*b-2*b*d*f-a*c*g)
        down1=(b*b-a*c)*( (c-a)*np.sqrt(1+4*b*b/((a-c)*(a-c)))-(c+a))
        down2=(b*b-a*c)*( (a-c)*np.sqrt(1+4*b*b/((a-c)*(a-c)))-(c+a))
        res1=np.sqrt(up/down1)
        res2=np.sqrt(up/down2)
        #Assert res1 is the major axis and res2 is the minor axis
        if(res2 > res1):
                tmp = res2
                res2 = res1
                res1 = tmp
        return np.array([res1, res2])

def ellipse_angle_of_rotation2( a ):
        b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
        if a > c:
                return np.arctan(2*b/(a-c))/2
        else:
                return np.pi/2 + np.arctan(2*b/(a-c))/2
```

Here is an example of a dataset that does NOT work as ellipse is rotated 90 deg. You can see this in this plot https://i.stack.imgur.com/khpel.png:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
x = np.array([40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 40.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 41.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 42.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 43.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 45.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 46.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 47.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 50.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 51.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 52.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 53.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 55.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 56.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 57.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 58.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 59.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 61.5])

y = np.array([42.5, 43.5, 46.5, 48.5, 49.5, 50.5, 51.5, 52.5, 54.5, 56.5, 57.5, 60.5, 41.5, 44.5, 45.5, 47.5, 53.5, 55.5, 57.5, 59.5, 60.5, 33.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 40.5, 58.5, 60.5, 62.5, 63.5, 64.5, 32.5, 34.5, 35.5, 36.5, 61.5, 64.5, 28.5, 29.5, 31.5, 65.5, 66.5, 67.5, 68.5, 71.5, 27.5, 30.5, 69.5, 70.5, 72.5, 24.5, 25.5, 26.5, 73.5, 74.5, 75.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 76.5, 78.5, 79.5, 18.5, 19.5, 77.5, 79.5, 16.5, 17.5, 80.5, 16.5, 17.5, 81.5, 82.5, 18.5, 79.5, 80.5, 81.5, 19.5, 20.5, 21.5, 23.5, 78.5, 22.5, 24.5, 25.5, 75.5, 76.5, 77.5, 24.5, 26.5, 27.5, 28.5, 73.5, 74.5, 29.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 69.5, 70.5, 71.5, 72.5, 33.5, 65.5, 66.5, 67.5, 68.5, 34.5, 35.5, 36.5, 64.5, 37.5, 38.5, 59.5, 60.5, 61.5, 63.5, 39.5, 41.5, 57.5, 58.5, 62.5, 40.5, 42.5, 43.5, 44.5, 45.5, 46.5, 47.5, 48.5, 49.5, 51.5, 52.5, 53.5, 54.5, 55.5, 56.5, 50.5])
```

And here is an example of a dataset for which the code works as you can see in this plot https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYTrS.png:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
x = np.array([25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 26.5, 27.5, 27.5, 27.5, 27.5, 28.5, 28.5, 29.5, 29.5, 30.5, 30.5, 31.5, 31.5, 32.5, 32.5, 33.5, 33.5, 34.5, 34.5, 35.5, 35.5, 36.5, 36.5, 37.5, 37.5, 38.5, 38.5, 39.5, 39.5, 40.5, 40.5, 41.5, 41.5, 42.5, 42.5, 43.5, 43.5, 44.5, 44.5, 45.5, 45.5, 46.5, 46.5, 47.5, 47.5, 48.5, 48.5, 49.5, 49.5, 49.5, 50.5, 50.5, 51.5, 51.5, 52.5, 52.5, 53.5, 53.5, 54.5, 54.5, 55.5, 55.5, 56.5, 56.5, 57.5, 57.5, 58.5, 58.5, 59.5, 59.5, 60.5, 60.5, 61.5, 61.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 63.5, 63.5, 64.5, 64.5, 65.5, 65.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 68.5, 68.5, 68.5, 69.5, 69.5, 70.5, 70.5, 70.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 71.5, 72.5, 72.5])

y = np.array([54.5, 55.5, 57.5, 50.5, 53.5, 56.5, 58.5, 50.5, 51.5, 52.5, 58.5, 49.5, 58.5, 48.5, 58.5, 48.5, 59.5, 47.5, 60.5, 46.5, 61.5, 45.5, 61.5, 44.5, 60.5, 44.5, 60.5, 43.5, 61.5, 42.5, 60.5, 42.5, 60.5, 42.5, 61.5, 41.5, 61.5, 40.5, 61.5, 40.5, 61.5, 39.5, 61.5, 39.5, 61.5, 39.5, 62.5, 38.5, 61.5, 38.5, 61.5, 38.5, 61.5, 37.5, 61.5, 62.5, 37.5, 60.5, 37.5, 61.5, 38.5, 60.5, 37.5, 60.5, 37.5, 60.5, 37.5, 60.5, 37.5, 59.5, 37.5, 59.5, 36.5, 58.5, 37.5, 57.5, 36.5, 58.5, 37.5, 57.5, 36.5, 37.5, 56.5, 38.5, 55.5, 38.5, 55.5, 37.5, 54.5, 38.5, 39.5, 53.5, 54.5, 38.5, 40.5, 52.5, 39.5, 40.5, 52.5, 41.5, 51.5, 40.5, 49.5, 50.5, 41.5, 42.5, 43.5, 44.5, 47.5, 48.5, 45.5, 46.5])
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
s = fitEllipse(x,y)
center = ellipse_center(s)
phi = ellipse_angle_of_rotation2(s)
axes = ellipse_axis_length(s)
print("The angle of rotation is", (phi*180/np.pi))
# get the individual axes
a, b = axes
ell = Ellipse(center, 2*a, 2*b, phi* (180 / np.pi), facecolor='none', edgecolor='black' )

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})
ax.add_artist(ell)
ell.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
scat = plt.scatter(x, y, c = "r", s = 1)
plt.show()
```

I want to make the SAME code work for both datasets.

Comment: Hi, I think my original answer, you were referring to, only works in that special case. The original code has an intrinsic 90° problem. I think it is solved by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61607790/803359) Discussion with the author of the original version suggested that the  github version does not have the problem anymore, but that might be wrong. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

A very robust method is shown below (Valid any angle of rotation).
[image]

From the coefficients of the above equation it is easy to compute the coordinates of the center, the length of axes, the angle of rotation, the foci, ... of the ellipse. See Eqs. (15-21) in : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html

More general information in : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14819165/Regressions-coniques-quadriques-circulaire-spherique (Edited in French).

Note that this method is valid to fit hyperbola as well. Of course the method is far to be new. This can be found in general litterature about fitting polynomial functions.