# How can I fit a circle (ideally an ellipse) to latitude/longitude scatter points in Cartopy?

Tags: coordinates, patch, projection, cartopy, ellipse

I simply want a best-fitting ellipse or circle for scatter data I have. I have been able to fit a circle to the data using numerous packages, but then the results are clearly nonsense. Maybe I need to do something weird to get results that work (a) for lat/lon data and (b) with Cartopy projections?

I have the following array of longitude/latitude values:

```
coords = np.array([-153.1906979 ,   62.01707771],
       [  13.05660412,   63.15537447],
       [-175.82610203,   67.11698477],
       [ -10.31730643,   61.74562855],
       [ 168.02402748,   79.60818152],
       [ -34.46162907,   65.10894426],
       [ -57.20962503,   59.49626998],
       [ 113.70202771,   68.22239091],
       [ -80.43411993,   55.6654176 ],
       [  93.77252509,   76.19392633],
       [-104.10892084,   56.68264351],
       [  66.36158188,   67.59664968],
       [-127.75176924,   57.31577071],
       [-151.83057714,   61.64142205],
       [  17.44848859,   56.02194986],
       [-176.30087703,   66.5955554 ],
       [  -5.48747931,   61.95844561],
       [ 160.22917767,   66.07650153],
       [ -27.93440014,   67.82152994],
       [ 137.09393573,   63.71148003],
       [ -53.3290508 ,   55.79699915],
       [ 109.42329666,   75.43090294],
       [ -76.59105583,   59.18143738],
       [  89.94733587,   63.50658353],
       [-100.54585734,   55.16704225],
       [  66.15810397,   64.64851675],
       [-123.65415058,   60.14507524],
       [  41.00262656,   70.67714209],
       [-145.66917977,   68.55315102],
       [  18.34306395,   67.62222778])
```

I plot them on a map as following:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121,projection=ccrs.NearsidePerspective(central_longitude=0, central_latitude=90,
                                                             satellite_height=30785831))

ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'ocean', '50m', facecolor='#daf7f7', alpha=0.7, zorder=0))
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '50m', facecolor='#ebc7a4', edgecolor='black', alpha=0.7,zorder=0))

ax.set_global()

grid = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
grid.xlabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'black'}
grid.ylabel_style = {'size': 20, 'color': 'black'}


ax.scatter(coords[0:,0], coords[0:,1], c='red', s=40, zorder=1, transform=PlateCarree())
```

[I get this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKYi3.png)

All I now want to do is fit an ellipse or a circle to this scatter data. Using the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52877062/17583970, I cannot even try plot anything because the b axis of the ellipse is just a nan. Using skg.nsphere_fit() gave a radius of 433, which is obviously wrong or needs transforming in some way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you show us what you've tried for your specific problem, and show us where/how it's not working? check out the guide to creating a [mre] - you're partway there but rather than guessing how you've adapted this other answer to your problem it's helpful if we can see your work. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates you use really matter in this case. Any fitting will use some sort of distance metric that's being minimized, and the distance in lat/lon coordinates doesn't reflect something in meters or miles at all:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid

If you're willing to assume that your map projection is a reasonable distance metric you can simply transform the coordinates, and perform the fit on those. I suspect that in this case the fit will be slightly biassed towards the pole (center of the map), making the ellipse a little smaller than it would be when fitted using the actual distance on the earths surface.

Using Cartopy to define the projections of your data and map:

```py
data_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
map_proj = ccrs.NearsidePerspective(central_longitude=0, central_latitude=90, satellite_height=30785831)
```

Those can then be used to convert the coordinates to the map projection:

```py
coords_map = map_proj.transform_points(data_proj, coords[:,0], coords[:,1])[:, :-1]
```

Fitting (and predicting) an ellipse using Scikit-Image:

```py
from skimage.measure import EllipseModel

model = EllipseModel()
model.estimate(coords_map)
ellipse_coords = model.predict_xy(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100))
```

That gives the vertices of the ellipse in the map projection. You could consider converting them back to lat/lon, which would allow you to use `ccrs.Geodetic` and have Cartopy plot the segments as great circles. But sampling the predicted ellipse in map coordinates might already be fine.

This results in:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6), subplot_kw=dict(projection=map_proj), dpi=86, facecolor="w")

ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'ocean', '110m', facecolor='#C6EEFF', alpha=1, zorder=0))
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '110m', facecolor='#A2BAA4', edgecolor='none', alpha=1,zorder=0))

ax.set_global()
grid = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, lw=0.5, color="k", alpha=0.2)

ax.plot(coords_map[0:,0], coords_map[0:,1], "o", mfc="none", mec='#A70000', mew=1, ms=5, zorder=1, transform=map_proj)
ax.plot(ellipse_coords[:, 0], ellipse_coords[:,1], "-", color="#A70000", transform=map_proj)
```

[image]

Comment: I thought some sort of transformation would be needed but could not find anything anywhere. Thank you SO MUCH for this!